# Icon on Tab Bar items

Tags: iphone

What is the requirement of the icon for Tab Bar item ?

I tried to use a 57 x 41 icons (.jpg - Full color). But it shows something (not my icons completely).

Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

By 'icon for tab bar item' you mean the tab bar item image right?
Tab Bar Item class reference clearly says:

> The item’s image. If nil, an image is not displayed.
>   The images displayed on the tab bar are derived from this image. If this image is too large to fit on the tab bar, it is scaled to fit. The size of an tab bar image is typically 30 x 30 points. The alpha values in the source image are used to create the unselected and selected images—opaque values are ignored.

Also, you mention you image to be 'full color'. Hope you don't expect to see this colored image in the tab bar item, cause u can't. As mentioned above, only 'alpha' values of image matter.